# how to update when the radiobutton is checked for the calculated number of days

Tags: c#

```
   try
            {

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring);
                con.Open();
                String sql = String.Format("update leavetable set status = '" + status + "' where eid = '" + textBox1.Text + "' and status = 'NULL'");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("status updated");
                    textBox1.Text = "";
                    textBox2.Text = "";
                    textBox3.Text = "";
                    textBox4.Text = "";
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
            }
```

Here I am displaying the `leavetable` details into the textboxes and I have `radiobuttons` as approved or cancelled.

When the admin selects the approved `radiobutton` and clicks on ok, I want to update the status as approved for that `empid` but empid is not primary key. but when i do that it will update all the rows which has the empid as `emp001` for example

Comment: I'm not clear what's not working in your code?

Comment: here come the SQLi comments...

Comment: Isn't that the almost same question asked an hour ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075036/update-command-is-not-working

Comment: Where do people learn string concatenated query strings like that? :/

Comment: no this is a different one

Comment: i want to update the attendance table in that status field has to be updated as leave for the number of days leave applied by the employee if the admin approves the leave

Comment: how to do it.. i am not getting any idea

Answer (score 1):

it's hard for me to understand what you are trying to say...

The `RadioButton` provides a `Checked` event. If you subscribe to it you can run your update query every time the event is triggered (It also has an `Unchecked` event...).

When using `String.Format` try make use of the advantage to write a nice unbroken string with placeholders inline that will be replaced by actual values at run time instead of ripping it off. This is more readable.

```
...
myRadioButton.Checked += RunUpdateQuery_OnRadioButtonChecked;

private void RunUpdateQuery_OnRadioButtonChecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
  try
  {    
      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
      {
          connection.Open();
          String updateQuery = String.Format("UPDATE leavetable SET status = '{0}'  
                                   WHERE eid = '{1}  AND status = 'NULL'",   
                                   status, textBox1.Text);
          SqlCommand commad = new SqlCommand(updateQuerry, connection);
          if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("status updated");
              textBox1.Text = "";
              textBox2.Text = "";
              textBox3.Text = "";
              textBox4.Text = "";
          }
       }
   }
   catch (Exception er)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
   }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the query executed on aproval by admin, and this control is set by a radiobutton add the code on `event checked` of your `radiobutton`:

```
  private void Radiobutton1_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
      try
         {    
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring);
           con.Open(); 
           using (con)
             {          
                String sql = "update leavetable set status =@status where eid =@ID  and status = 'NULL'");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox1.Text);
                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("status updated");
                    textBox1.Text = "";
                    textBox2.Text = "";
                    textBox3.Text = "";
                    textBox4.Text = "";
                }
              }
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
            }      
    }
```

**EDIT :**

If `eid` isnt an index in your table (there multiple rows with same id) then obviously the update will be done in multiple records. This fact has to do with your query set up and no with programming.

It is up to you to decide what condition you want to choose for correct updating the records of your table.

Much likely you need to add an extra where clause , if I correctly understand you have a timestamp field `nooofdays`, you can use this too:

```
update leavetable set status =@status where eid =@ID and nooofdays=@param1 and status = 'NULL'");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", textBox2.Text);
```

Hope it helps, because it fairly diffult to understand you...

Comment: You are filtering by null value and by eId where this id is a shared value. You need to have a field that is not shared and include it into your WHERE condition...

Comment: then what to do should i have to change the table structure

Comment: that status field will be empty untill the admin checks once he checks as approved then it will be filled as approved or cancelled so i have taken as NULL

Comment: Yes i think i understand but you need to identify this employee, right? And this identifier needs to be unique, ok?

Comment: ya you are right sir shall i change the table structure shall i add a field as password which is unique

Comment: No. Apomene's approach may work for you. Include the noooofdays field into the query and it should work (only if this field is not shared by other records)

Comment: You add it to the WHERE clause as another AND block

Comment: if indeed is a timestamp the the pair eid,noofdays will be unique. If it isn't a timestamp it wont be...(make sure to take up to msecs if its timestamp)

Comment: sir noofdays is the difference between to - from days of leave sir